# Why is $\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{2k-1}{36}=\frac{1}{18}\sum_{k=1}^{6}k-\frac{1}{6}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why is 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{2k-1}{36} = \frac{1}{18}\sum_{k=1}^{6}k-\frac{1}{6}?
$$

Answer (score 3):

There can be ambiguity when using the $\sum$ symbol: which terms are included and which aren't? To avoid confusion, it's best to use parentheses:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{2k-1}{36} &= \sum_{k=1}^{6}\left(\frac{2k}{36}-\frac1{36}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{k}{18}\right) - \left(\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac1{36}\right)\\
&=\frac1{18}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{6}k\right) - 6\left(\frac1{36}\right)\\
&=\frac1{18}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{6}k\right) - \frac16\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh. You are right. They probably meant that.